# Which church denomination has a very strong emphasis on the prophecies of Daniel and Revelation?

Tags: prophecy, revelation, daniel, denomination

I was wondering which church denominations have a very strong emphasis in the prophecies of Daniel and Revelation since it seems they are linked to one another?

Comment: Your question made me pull out a 699-page book published in 1908, written by an Adventist named Uriah Smith. It is entitled, "Daniel and The Revelation". I also have far more recent books interpreting those two Bible books, published by Jehovah's Witnesses, and (like Adventism) their chronology of end-time beliefs is based on them. I would include those still supporting T.G. Armstrong of "The Plain Truth" series, but there are many others. Denominations that say you must belong to them to survive Armageddon are inclined to keep producing ever-up-dated interpretations based on current events.

Comment: Wow, sounds like an interesting book that one with the 699 pages. Would you include Seventh-day Adventists as those who say you must belong to their denomination to survive Armageddon?

Comment: I am always suspicious of any ministry which 'emphasises' prophecies about the future. The emphasis of the New Testament writings is, primarily, repentance and faith and salvation, and the birth, baptism, ministry, sufferings, death, bloodshed, resurrection, ascension and return of Jesus Christ, the Son of God.

Comment: @Anne very good book that of Uriah Smith. I like the details he gives about Daniel 11.

Comment: The book interpreted Napoleon Bonaparte's [then] recent exploits as proof of fulfilled prophecies, and that 'the end' was about to happen. Once I saw that, and how utterly wrong it was, I laid it aside. I would hope an Adventist (Seventh-Day or otherwise) would answer your question to me, as I'm not one.

Comment: @NigelJ I have appreciation for your suspicion as I used to belong to a very orthodox denomination that taught its members to be suspicious about anything other than what they are saying. They happened to also get stuck on the same points of faith you mentioned. I look back today at that church and it is clear that their suspicion of others was a cover for their ignorance of topics outside their comfort zone.

Comment: @Anne Don't throw out the baby with the bath water, there is a lot there that is great work. Chew the meat and spit out the bones is what I do with authors like Smith.

Comment: In my experience it's very common in dispensationalism churches too.

Answer (score 1):

The Seventh-day Adventist Church has a very strong emphasis on the prophecies of the two books you are asking about. They claim to understand much of the symbolism in these prophecies but say prophecy means much more than telling the future. Here is a link to their website description on [prophecy](https://www.adventist.org/gift-of-prophecy/prophecy/?searchsite=www.adventist.org&ref=on-site-search&searchterm=Prophecy)